# ListView32 - re-adding column doesn't restore data

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm implementing show/hide column behaviour in a standard C++ Win32 application (no frameworks).

Say we've got 3 columns in a ListView control in Details view. The user has the option to show/hide the last two columns in order to see the extra detail if wanted or hide them to reduce clutter. All works well *except* that after the columns are deleted and then re-added, the data from the sub-items in those columns doesn't show up again, i.e. the columns are empty.

None of the items themselves have been altered in the meantime - do I lose the sub-item text when I delete the columns or I am missing something to force the columns to redraw the data?

Steps to reproduce:

1) Create a ListView32 control with 3 columns and add a bunch of items (and text to each of the items' sub-items). All good.

2) The user clicks "Hide Details", so I use LVM_DELETECOLUMN twice to remove the last two columns and they disappear. All good.

3) The user clicks "Show Details", so I use LVM_INSERTCOLUMN to add the last two columns and the headings appear, but the columns themselves are empty.

As an alternative, setting the column widths to zero is a hack and the user can still grab the re-size column splitter, so it's not a great option.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Typically one does not store data in GUI. In case of plain listview32 you should add items specifying `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` instead of real text and then handle [`LVN_GETDISPINFOW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774818.aspx) notification supplying (sub)item data. Windows will send this notification for all items. You can force Windows to retrieve data again by sending [`LVM_UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761230.aspx) message.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, another option would be to go full virtual, i.e. use a [virtual list-view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style). That way you don't even have to add any items, but still get the callback behavior.

Comment: Many thanks @VTT. I've got a bunch of other ListView's which are virtual so they aren't subject to this behaviour. I'm hoping to eventually get these particular show/hide ListView's replaced with an entirely different UI mechanism, so I didn't want to devote any more refactoring on them to make them more "legitimate" if you know what I mean. :)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the column widths is a viable solution. That is the way I do it in my UIs when columns can be shown and hidden dynamically.  It works fine.

To prevent the user from resizing "hidden" columns, simply subclass the ListView using [`SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) or [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) to intercept [`HDN_BEGINTRACK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775263.aspx) notifications from the ListView's header control:

> Notifies a header control's parent window that **the user has begun dragging a divider in the control** (that is, the user has pressed the left mouse button while the mouse cursor is on a divider in the header control). This notification code is sent in the form of a `WM_NOTIFY` message.
>
> ...
>
> Returns `FALSE` to allow tracking of the divider, or **`TRUE` to prevent tracking**.